# Rails Serializer output naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

Hopefully someone can help me.

I noticed that the json output formatted using the serializer takes the name of the serializer. i.e. if the serializer I use is user_input_serializer, the JSON object would be {
user_input: {...}
}. And if the serializer is blah_blah_serializer then the output would be { blah_blah:{...}}

I am wondering if I can just make that leading tag the same regardless of what serializer I use.

EDIT:

Some code for example

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :first_name, 
 :last_name, 
 :email, 
 :gender,
 :chat_handle, 
 :position, 
 :location,
 :status
end

class UserShortSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :first_name, 
 :last_name, 
 :email
end
```

Say I have this two classes to serialize the same user model in two different situations...somehow the json output in the REST api would lead with a { "user": {...}} and {"user_short":{...}} respectively.  This is creating some potential parsing problem for our client applications?

Comment: Please add some code example and results. It's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ActiveModel::Serializer` you can either remove the root key with something like:

```
UserShortSerializer.new(User.first).to_json(root: false)
```

Or you can change its name with:

```
UserShortSerializer.new(User.first).to_json(root: "my_root_name")
```

If you want a certain behavior to be used across the board, you can create a file in the `config/initializers` folder and set `ActiveModel::Serializer.root = "my_default_name"`.  Then if you don't specify a different root name when retrieving the serialized data, the default name will be used.  You can also adjust defaults using the `default_serializer_options` method in a controller.

More info can be found in the [active_model_serializers documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) and in [RailsCast #409 - Active Model Serializers](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers).